# Functional Consumer and Producer with Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, functional-programming, spring-cloud-stream

In my springboot application I need to consume message from 2 different kafka topics.

From the first topic all messages follow the same elaboration.
From the second topic I need to do 2 different elaboration by an header value.

In the past I used @StreamListener, but now is deprecated.
How can I configure the new consumer in the application.yml with a clean code?

I saw only one example with MessageRoutingCallback, but I don't like to use a single Router for all the topic because I don't want to keep all the "if" statement to divide the elaboration.

I tried to define 2 routers and 2 consumers but the application doesn't start because can't accept two bean.
This is the error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 3 of method functionRouter in org.springframework.cloud.function.context.config.ContextFunctionCatalogAutoConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - firstMessageRouter: defined in file [C:\Workspace-IntelliJ\TEST\test-kafka-cloud-stream\target\classes\org\example\router\FirstMessageRouter.class]
    - secondMessageRouter: defined in file [C:\Workspace-IntelliJ\TEST\test-kafka-cloud-stream\target\classes\org\example\router\SecondMessageRouter.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class FirstMessageRouter implements MessageRoutingCallback {
    @Override
    public FunctionRoutingResult routingResult(Message<?> message) {
        log.info("First router");
        log.info("Headers: " + message.getHeaders());
        log.info("Payload: " + message.getPayload());

        return new MessageRoutingCallback.FunctionRoutingResult("firstconsumer");
    }
}
```

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class SecondMessageRouter implements MessageRoutingCallback {
    @Override
    public FunctionRoutingResult routingResult(Message<?> message) {
        log.info("Second router");
        log.info("Headers: " + message.getHeaders());
        log.info("Payload: " + message.getPayload());

        return new FunctionRoutingResult("second-consumer");
    }
}
```

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class FirstConsumer implements Consumer<Message<?>> {
    @Override
    public void accept(Message<?> message) {
        log.info("Received message in FirstConsumer with payload: " + message.getPayload() + " and headers: " + message.getHeaders());
    }
}
```

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class SecondConsumer implements Consumer<Message<?>> {
    @Override
    public void accept(Message<?> message) {
        log.info("Received message in SecondConsumer with payload: " + message.getPayload() + " and headers: " + message.getHeaders());
    }
}
```

My configuration is this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        firstMessageRouter-in-0:
          destination: topic-1-input
          group: group-3
        secondMessageRouter-in-0:
          destination: topic-2-input
          group: group-4
      kafka:
        streams:
          defaultBrokerPort: 9092
          brokers: localhost
```

I'm sure I miss something, especially on Functional programming.
Can someone explain in which way is possible to implement various consumer?

I also tried to declare consumer in a Configuration class with this other application.yml, but if I need different elaboration I need to import all the service here and I prefer to don't do it.

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Bean("first-process")
    public Consumer<Message<?>> process() {
        return message -> {
            log.info("Received headers: " + message.getHeaders());
            log.info("Received payload: " + message.getPayload());
            
        };
    }

    @Bean("second-process")
    Consumer<String> topic1() {
        return str -> {
            log.info("Received message in topic1: " + str);
        };
    }
}
```

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: first-process; second-process
      bindings:
        first-process-in-0:
          destination: topic.input
          group: group-1
        second-process-in-0:
          destination: topic-1
          group: group-2
      kafka:
        streams:
          defaultBrokerPort: 9092
          brokers: localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, the point of any router is to provide routing to other functionalities so it can only be done via `IF/ELSE` statements. In StreamListener you were exposed to the same `IF/ELSE` mechanism although thru direct connectivity to message channels which is an internal detail that should have never been exposed in the first place.

Aside from supporting `MessageRoutingCallback` we support SpEL expressions as well which work very well when routing based on the header value, but if your routing logic is complex the `MessageRoutingCallback` is a way to go. - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_routing_to_consumer Having multiple instances of `MessageRoutingCallback` will only pollute your code and it feels like an anti-pattern since you are not doing any routing there at all.